# Is there a way to hide a product on category page based on its name?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to not load some products on category page based on its name. Googling I found some examples with taxonomies, which doesn't help me at all. So, how can I edit the code below to fit in my needs? Thx!

```
function check_variations( $q ) {
    
    if ( $outofstock_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'outofstock', 'product_visibility' ) ) {

        $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms' => array( $outofstock_term->term_taxonomy_id ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );

        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'check_variations' );
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am really new on Woocommerce. Although It's my first time working on it, I didn't had much difficulties along the way. But I have a problem: Since  it's really painful working with products variations, I made a json file with the available variations depending on the category of the product (there are a tons of variations - 91 each product). On product page, I made with js and it's working just fine. Now, I just want to hide some products on the filter page category. Here is my php reading the json:

```
function check_variations( $q ) {
    $page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (strpos($page_url, '?filter_modelo=') !== false) {
        $filter = explode('?filter_modelo=', $page_url)[1];
    }

    if($filter) {
        $json_data = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri().'/release/json/variations-in-stock.json');
        $json_decoded = json_decode($json_data, true);

        foreach($json_decoded as $key => $value){
            if (strpos(implode(",", $value[0]), $filter) !== false) {
                //var_dump($key);
                //Here I want to hide products with $key on its name
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'check_variations' );
```

**UPDATE 2**

I made it by content-product.php file. It worked, but it bugs the pagination... I am trying to add this code to functions.php but I don't know how which action/filter I have to use to get the post/product name and also prevent the pagination bug.

```
$page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$product_name = $product->get_title();

if (strpos($page_url, 'filter_modelo=') !== false) {
    $filter = explode('filter_modelo=', $page_url)[1];
    $json_data = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri().'/release/json/variations-in-stock.json');
    $json_decoded = json_decode($json_data, true);

    foreach($json_decoded as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($filter, explode(', ', $value[0]['modelos']))) {
            if (strpos($product_name, $key) !== false) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just so i can get this correct your trying to not display out of stock items in your category page?

Comment: No. I'm trying to modify de code that not display out of stock items to not display a product with a specifc name.

Comment: i would use wc_get_products and a custom filter https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support

Comment: Ok! I'll take a look.

Comment: in your product array you are looking for post_name but you do have other options like a targeting slug or id if you are attempting to get and individual product

Comment: I just updated my question so you can better understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think I can solve my issue with [Post & Page Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). But I don't know how to use it.